# Run docker container on azure

Tags: azure, docker

I have a simple docker container which runs just fine on my local machine. I was hoping to find an easy checklist how I could publish and run my docker container on Azure, but couldn't find one. I only found https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/, but this document kind of leaves me alone when it comes to actually copy my local docker container to Azure. Isn't that supposed to be very easy? Can anybody point me in the right direction how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

But it is really easy.. once you know where to find the docs :-). I would take the [azure docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) as a starting point as there are multiple options when it comes to hosting containers in Azure:

> If you're looking for this...
>
> Simplify the deployment, management, and operations of Kubernetes -> Azure Container Service (AKS)
>
> Easily run containers on Azure with a single command -> Container Instances
>
> Store and manage container images across all types of Azure deployments
>    -> Container Registry
>
> Develop microservices and orchestrate containers on Windows or Linux
>    -> Service Fabric
>
> Deploy web applications on Linux using containers
>   -> App Service

Based on your info I would suggest storing the image using the [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/) and host the container using [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/). No need for a VM to manage this way.

There is an [excellent tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr) you could follow (I skipped the first 1 step since it involves creating a docker image, you already have one)

Another complete guide of pushing your image to azure and create a running container can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-powershell#view-the-application).

The good thing about Azure Container Instances is that you only pay for what you actually use. The Azure Container Registry is a private image repository hosted in Azure, if course you could also use Docker Hub but using ACR makes it all really simple.

Comment: thanks, the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr) really helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to run an image, you simply need to configure a new VM with the Docker Daemon.  I personally found Azure's documentation to be pretty complex.  Assuming you are not trying to scale your service across instances, I would recommend using `docker-machine` rather than the Azure guide.

   `docker-machine` is a CLI tool published by the Docker team which automatically installs the Docker Daemon (and all the dependencies) on a host.  So all you would need to do is [input your Azure subscription](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/) and it will automatically create a VM configured appropriately.
2. In terms of publishing the image, Azure is probably not the right solution.  I would recommend one of two things:

   - Use [Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/), which serves as a free hosted Docker image repository.  You can simply push images to Docker Hub (or even have them built directly from your Git repository).
   - Configure a CD tool, such as TravisCI or CircleCI, and use these to build your image and push directly to your deployment.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the second point as to why azure is not the right solution for publishing images?

Comment: @PeterBons The "Azure solution" would be to create a private container registry, which seems like overkill for a single container/single node instance.

Answer (score 0):

To run your docker image inside ACI, You can use of Azure Container Registry.

Step0: Create Azure Container Registry

Step1: Include a Dockerfile in your application code

Step2: Build the code along with the Dockerfile with a tag and create a 
Docker image ( docker build -t imagename:tag .)

Step3: Push the Docker image to Azure container Registry with a image name and tag.

Step4: Now create a ACI, while creating, choose the image type as private, provide the image name, tag, image registry login server, image registry username, image registry password ( these details can be found under access keys tab inside Azure Container Registry)

Step5: choose running os as linux, in network step you can give an dns name for your ACI, then click on review & create

Step6: once ACI gets created you can go to overview and you can see fqdn, using fqdn you can access your application running inside Azure Container Instance.